# Kentico 10 : How to find the file uploaded by DirectUploadControl

Tags: kentico

We are using Kentico 10

**Question 1**

We are using DirectUploadControl to upload image in a page form.

We have column PDFImage in the page type. I can see the value of this field to be a GUID.

Where the image is stored on disk when uploaded by this control? Which table is updated with file name?

I tried the page type table, cms document and media file but couldn't find.

**Question 2**

We need to process the image when uploaded. Is there an event? Right now we are doing this in DocumentEvents.SaveVersion.After

Answer (score 0):

1. This depends on how the system is set to [store files](https://docs.xperience.io/k10/configuring-kentico/managing-files/storing-files). So, it can be in the DB or on disk or both. When on disk, it depends what folder is set to store the attachments.
2. In the [document events](https://docs.xperience.io/k10/custom-development/handling-global-events/reference-global-system-events) there is the **SaveAttachment** event - so maybe you can try using that one. Or, it might be better to create a custom uploader form control - depending on your needs.